# How can I map an array of types to another array of types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have this:

```js
type CoolTuple = [string, number, boolean]
```

And, I want to map that type using some generic:

```js
type CoolGeneric<T extends any[]> = ...
```

Such that:

```js
CoolGeneric<CoolType> is [Wrapper<string>, Wrapper<number>, Wrapper<boolean>]
```

What would I do?

Answer (score 2):

You want a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type CoolGeneric<T extends any[]> = { [K in keyof T]: Wrapper<T[K]> }
```

Basically, for each key (indices of a tuple are keys), declare the type to be something that uses the property type `T[K]`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4&ssl=5&ssc=70&pln=5&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9nANgFQK5kdAvFA2gZ2ACcBLAOwHMAaKM1AWwCMIibGFMBDMgXQCg+oSFADqRTmEhEAPMgB8UHAG8oAd3GSIAEwBcUZFAC+AodHhIA4hDIsSAY1lQIAD2DWt+KNxC4eC5XgA0lDkUADWECBwAGb6PHpiElKyuIF+RgJ2cGSEUG6EeuaIVjakDkVoGBD+eCrqSdp6AOSc+FpNhjR1GpC6UACMAEwAzJ1Q3Q19xKgQhjxAA)

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize this worked for arrays.

Comment: A tuple is basically just an object with sequential integer keys.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense.

Comment: "a tuple is basically just an object with sequential integer keys"... well, it also has non-integer keys like `"length"` and `"push"` and you don't want to map those (so that you get a `length` of type `Wrapper<number>` and a `push` of type `Wrapper<(...items: (string | number | boolean)[]) => number>`).  TypeScript 3.1 added support to [have mapped types turn arrays/tuples into arrays/tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) and that change *stopped* treating them like "just an object".

Comment: @AlexWayne I just started running into a situation where this creates unions of the wrapper types as opposed to interpreting them as a progressive tuple? Any idea why this could be?